# What techniques exist for ensuring production environment variables are persisted in some form within a project?

Tags: configuration, environment-variables, infrastructure, 12factor

Apologies for title phrasing; I'm sure it could be clearer.

In the Twelve-Factor App methodology, we are encouraged to store web app configuration using environment variables. When using a managed platform such as Heroku, this configuration is safely persisted as a feature of the platform, automatically made available to each deployment, and readily inspectable by developers. This feature is assumed to be stable and, as far as I know, no separate copy of production config need be maintained elsewhere.

When using a simpler unmanaged deployment process, e.g. `git push`-ing non-containerised code to a VPS, environment variables can still be used (e.g. a non-source-controlled `.env` file) but they are now effectively ephemeral, and if the VPS is destroyed through some error or incident, the project can be redeployed elsewhere but the configuration variables will need to be reconstructed from something.

My question is, in such a scenario, what is considered best practice around what that "something" should be? When joining a new project I can often `cp .env.example .env` to set up a typical local configuration. The values in the example file are usually safe to save in source control. However, I don't know where (if anywhere) I should be saving production configuration in order that I could configure a new production deployment of the kind described above. In the Heroku example, the configuration can always be inspected. But in the VPS example, if that running VPS is the only location where the complete production configuration exists, its unexpected disappearance presents a problem.

Obviously any credentials in the config could be regenerated, but that could quickly turn into a non-trivial exercise. I'm wondering how more experienced folks deal with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: Hey, did you found the best way to do this?

Comment: @AlexanderV Not yet – at the moment using a mixture of things including 1Password to save these sorts of credentials